# React Suspense causes router props to be undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router

I use Suspense as the following:

```
<Route
          path="/courses"
          render={() => (
            <Suspense fallback={HomePage}>
              <Courses />
            </Suspense>
          )}
        />
```

then, on Courses component, I try accessing the router props as the following:

```
<Link
            to={{
              pathname: this.props.match.url + "/" + course.id,
              search: "?title=" + course.title,
            }}
            key={course.id}
          >
```

However, router props turned into undefined.
Accessing these props has been possible until I tried adding this React.lazy loading.

I guess that since now Suspense is the component loaded, it receives all the routing props and does not pass them on to my component, but that's just a guess.

to solve it, I also tried the spread operator syntax: e.g `<Courses {...props} />` - which didn't work.

How do I access the router props while using React.lazy?

Thanks In Advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the `props` down:

```
<Route
      path="/courses"
      render={(props) => (
        <Suspense fallback={HomePage}>
          <Courses {...props}/>
        </Suspense>
      )}
    />
```

Or use [withRouter](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter) HOC

For functional components you can use [useRouteMatch](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useroutematch)